there are no `allow non-modular includes in framework modules`
XCode 16, I can't find Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules in Build Settings.
I'm having this issue and this is the key.
I added the following to the Podfile to resolve this issue.
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end


The item has been added to XCode, but the same problem occurs even if the value is set to "YES".
